# How to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 if I have dual boot with windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I have dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, and I would like to upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04 but still retain my windows 7, help! I have a DVD with the ubuntu 14.04 ISO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've burned the DVD correctly, and not just dragging the ISO onto the disc.

Then, pop it in, restart your computer, go into your boot menu, and select Optical Drive or CD/DVD Drive. (whatever your bios says).

The setup process will allow you to install it alongside Windows.

Also, please don't post duplicate questions. This is on here, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good internet connection, then you need not rely on your dvd. Just type in sudo update-manager -d in the terminal, and that should do it. Your dual boot system and the bootloader shouldn't be affected.

Otherwise, you can do what @cxdy suggested. You should be able to find lots of information about the whole process to guide you through.